# Hindu astrology - Problems with programming ascendant

Tags: python

I am working on a Hindu astrology software using PySwissEph which is a python library developed using [SwissEphemeris](http://www.astro.com/swisseph/swephinfo_e.htm) I am faced with a dilemma I can't solve. **The code is functional, but the ascendant is often determined to be incorrect** this is in comparison to other software such as [Maitreya](http://www.saravali.de/maitreya.html). I have posted the parts of the code I feel are relative but can post more if needed.

Edit * The ascendant is not accurate, it appears to have entire Zodiac sign differences in comparison to working software.

```
### SET SID MODE
set_ayanamsa_mode = lambda: swe.set_sid_mode(swe.SIDM_TRUE_CITRA, 0, 0)
set_ayanamsa_mode()
```

Above is the Ayanamsha to use

```
### TIMEZONE INFORMATION
tz = timezone(zone)
timecheck = tz.localize(datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0))
```

Above is to convert the timezone using pytz

```
jd = swe.utc_to_jd(timecheck.year, timecheck.month, timecheck.day, timecheck.hour, timecheck.minute, 0.1, 1)
jd = float(jd[1])
```

Above is swisseph function to convert utc time to a julian day

```
#ayan = swe.calc_ut(jd, swe.ECL_NUT)[0]
ayanamsa = swe.get_ayanamsa_ut(jd) #+ float(ayan)
```

I am not 100% certain about this code (Above). I have been experimenting for quite some time

```
### ASCENDANT
ascDeg = float(swe.houses_ex(jd, lat, lon, 'E', flag = swe.FLG_SWIEPH | swe.FLG_SIDEREAL | swe.FLG_SPEED)[0][4])
ascDeg = ascDeg - ayanamsa

if ascDeg < 0:
    360 + ascDeg

ascSign = int(ascDeg / 30) + 1
```

Above is the code to calculate the ascendant. The 'E' flag represents the use of the Equal house system in SwissEphemeris.

I appreciate any guidance given concerning this programming task. Thank you :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I've tried to explain further, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ascDeg < 0:
    360 + ascDeg
```

In the above conditional, you are not setting the value `360 + ascDeg` to `ascDeg`.

So, this should work:

```
if ascDeg < 0:
    ascDeg = 360 + ascDeg
```